# Arrow Rotation in speedometer

Tags: iphone, ios

I have implemented a speedometer. I have one arrow image. I want to rotate it 0° to 180° very smoothly with finger touch and also I should give boundaries. How is it possible?

Here is my code (in `UIImageView` category):

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    CGPoint pastLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.superview];

    CGPoint d1 = CGPointMake(currentLocation.x-self.superview.center.x, currentLocation.y-self.superview.center.y);   
    CGPoint d2 = CGPointMake(pastLocation.x-self.superview.center.x, pastLocation.y-self.superview.center.y);

    CGFloat angle1 = atan2(d1.y, d1.x); 
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2(d2.y, d2.x); 

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, angle1-angle2);
}
```

It's rotating 0 to 360 degrees, I need restrict between the angles like 20 to 160 degrees.

Comment: You'll get the best results from Stack Overflow if you provide some actual code and get feedback on that, rather than asking such a general question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210346/how-to-rotate-needle-just-like-car-speedo-meter-with-boundaries-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210346/how-to-rotate-needle-just-like-car-speedo-meter-with-boundaries-in-ios)

Answer (score 3):

Figure out the correct Affine Transform to apply based on touch (using trig) and apply it.

```
 view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
```

Probably you need to translate the origin first, and then back again, to get it to rotate around the point that you want.  Alternatively, you could make the view so that the pivot point is in the center of the view.

To calculate the angle, find the touch point's distance from the rotation point (dx, dy).

> tan angle = dy / dx

Use

```
 atan2(dy, dx)
```

Because it deals with the signs by knowing which quadrant it's in (don't pass in 0 for dx).

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atan2.3.html

Deal with the dx being 0 case separately (it's PI/2 radians).  There are probably other special cases you want to deal with to constrain it -- just pick min and max radians and check them before using in a transform.

EDIT based on question update:  You have done the hard part -- just look at the angle and limit it

Use MIN and MAX to limit angle1 and angle2 (remember it's radians, so `20/180*pi` and `160/180*pi`).  Do that right before you pass to CGAffineTransformRotate

Comment: but i need to restrict between the angles like 20 to 160 degrees (it's rotating 0 to 360 degrees)

Comment: Check the angle and restrict it using min and max (but you have to express it in radians) `radians = degrees / 180 * PI`

Comment: I am unable to find the exact solution:@Lou Franco , can u please fullfill above code

Comment: Try to program it yourself given the information and then if you run into problems, post your code and ask a specific question.